# Change the button text/value on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**My goal** is to include *Element.ID* within function and then, fetch their value or text. It is important to reduce code lines as well because there are many others buttons with the same rule.

So, I tried the below code and many others to get the appropriate results.

How do I fix it?

```js
var el = document.getElementById("p1");
var id = document.getElementById("p1").id;

el.addEventListener("click", modifyText(id), false);

function modifyText(e) {
  var x = e.value;
  if (x < 40) {
    e.value = 1;
  }
};
```

```html
<input id="p1" type="button" class="button" value=0>
<input id="pn" type="button" class="button" value=0>
```

Comment: what should this code do?

Comment: Here it is..

<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input id = "p1" type="button" class="button" value=0>
  <input id = "pn" type="button" class="button" value=0>
  <MyScript>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the second argument to `.addEventListener()` has to be a function reference, not "loose" code to execute. So, if you want to call another function and pass it an argument, the line should be:

```
el.addEventListener("click", function(){modifyText(id)}, false);
```

Now, you are making quite a bit out of the element's `id`, but you really only need the `id` to get your initial reference to the element. Once you've got that, you can just work with it.

You've got a lot of unnecessary code here. **Also, I'm assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that you want both buttons to have the same `click` behavior, so that's what I'm proceeding with.**

```js
// You only need to get a reference to the element in question
var el1 = document.getElementById("p1");
var el2 = document.getElementById("pn");

// Set up each button to use the same click callback function
// The second argument needs to be a function reference
el1.addEventListener("click", modifyText);
el2.addEventListener("click", modifyText);

function modifyText(){
 // When inside of an event handler, "this" refers to the element
 // that triggered the event.
 if (this.value < 40 ) {
  this.value = 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<input id = "p1" type="button" class="button" value=0> 
<input id = "pn" type="button" class="button" value=0>
```

Answer (score 0):

Event listener callbacks tend to be executed with the execution context of the element (unless otherwise modified, or using Arrow functions). This means you can just use `this` keyword to refer to the element. So inside the callback you could use `this.value` / `this.innerText` (depending on type of element)

```
function modifyText() {
 var x = this.value;
 if ( x < 40 ) {
  this.value = 1;
 }
}
```

Also the way you called addEventListener was wrong.

.addEventListener("click", modifyText(id), false);

This will execute `modifyText` immediately and use the return value of the function as the callback. And since your function doesnt return anything nothing is set as the callback.

If you wanted to pass a variable to an event callback you would do it like the following

```
el.addEventListener("click", modifyText.bind(el,yourValue),false);
```

You would then need to modify the function definition

```
function modifyText(passedValue,event) {

}
```